# Posting a sqlsrv array into a MySql table - PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, sqlsrv

I have started using PHP / MySql at work (where they only use Ms Sql) and I am looking to use the data from the companies severs and post into my MySql servers.

So far I have connected to the companies Sql Server and retrieved Data into an array but now I am looking to post this array into a MySql table.

Can I post the sqlsrv array via PHP / mysqli_query? or is there a better way of doing this? (Pretty new to all this)

Thanks

Comment: You can use php PDO class, it offers more abstraction here's a tutorial: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo or use a frawework (an advanced way)